# Timers in rebol3

Tags: rebol, rebol3

The Rebol3 source code shows a [timer port interface](https://github.com/rebol/r3/blob/master/src/core/p-timer.c) but at yet there is no timer device available.

What else needs to be done to get timers available for the GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@earl has implemented timers in an unpublished development branch of the Rebol3

I guess it will be published in due course.